# How do I use a Google Account for Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I have tried to make a new Trainers Club Account, but the site is down. Does anybody know how I can use my Google Account to make an account? Thanks.

Comment: Wait a while. The game has a huge popularity spike right now. It will diminish in a couple days/hours and you will be able to register then.

Comment: If you wish to use a Google account, it needs to be tied/synced with your device. Otherwise the game will never ask for you to sign in with it.

Comment: Why is this question protected?

Comment: @Evorlor "Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed". Also looks like the protection was done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

On the opening screen (after the Niantic logo screen) there are two buttons. The top one allows you to sign in with a Google account. Tapping it will present you with a pop-up menu of all the different Google accounts associated with your phone.

It's not the same color as the Trainer Club button, so it's easy to miss.

If you do not see the button, try uninstalling and reinstalling the Pokemon Go app, and when asked your age, saying you are over 13.

Comment: it doesn't show up its just the Trainer Club, and I have a google account synced with my device

Comment: Try reinstalling the app.

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: @RossVieira If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: You don't actually have to reinstall the app, just clear the cache. The very first time you start, if you pick a birthday so that your age is too young, then the Google Account option is removed.